# Is there a way to shorten this code: (Add key to dictionary if key doesn't exist)?

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
{
     dict[key] = value;
}
else
{
     dict.Add(key, value);
}
```

This is kind of verbose and I'm wondering if there is a magical function out there that can reduce this to 1 or 2 lines of code. Please teach me magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already the behaviour of the dictionary's index operator:

```cs
dict[key] = value;
```

Is all you need.